# What is meant by including "-p" as a "non-option argument" in the git stash push documentation?

Tags: git, git-stash

The `git stash push` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-S--staged-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--pathspec-from-fileltfilegt--pathspec-file-nul--ltpathspecgt82308203) states:

> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit "push". In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry. The two exceptions to this are `stash -p` which acts as alias for `stash push -p` and pathspec elements, which are allowed after a double hyphen `--` for disambiguation.

However, I'm confused by the `stash -p` example being listed as an exception to the non-option arguments.  Isn't `-p` an option argument?

For instance, the following also appears to be a valid use of omitting "push", and it creates a stash with the given message:

```
git stash -m "some commit message"
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?  Is this an issue with the documentation?

What is meant by including `stash -p` as an exception to disallowing the non-option arguments, when it appears to be an option argument.?

Comment: I think you're expecting much precision from someone (whoever wrote the doc here) who just used sloppy English instead of formal logic, but the Git folks *have* taken bug reports (especially with fixes) that clean this sort of stuff up. So feel free to take a stab at fixing the documentation and sending that in as a patch...

Answer (score 0):

A nonoption argument is, say, a filename.

Suppose you have an edited file called *clea*. Then it is forbidden to say

```
git stash clea
```

because, as the documentation says, we can't tell if `clea` is a misspelling for some subcommand such as `clear`. It would have been legal to say

```
git stash push clea
```

but Git is not about to *assume* you mean that.

But if you say

```
git stash -p -- clea
```

that's fine; you have disambiguated sufficiently, so it is just as if you had said

```
git stash push -p clea
```

and the success of the command depends merely on whether you do in fact have a file called *clea*.

Comment: I get that file names are non-option arguments.  However, it states that `stash -p` being an alias for `stash push -p` is an exception to not allowing non-option arguments.  If it's an exception to the rule, it implies that it's a non-option argument.  But `-p` clearly seems to be an option.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: No, it implies that if you use -p you do not have to say push in the presence of nonoption arguments. You keep misreading and I keep trying to correct your reading. Please reread my answer.